# execl() causes an application crash

Tags: c, windows, exec, tcc

I compiled and ran the following program with [TCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) under Windows 7 and got an application crash:

```
#include <process.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (execlp("c:\\windows\\system32\\whoami.exe", "c:\\windows\\system32\\whoami.exe") < 0)
        perror("error");

    return 1;
}
```

Here are the crash details:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   a.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  00000000
Fault Module Name:  msvcrt.dll
Fault Module Version:   7.0.7601.17744
Fault Module Timestamp: 4eeaf722
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   0005b4fe
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Why is it happening and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to null-terminate your list of arguments to `execlp()`.

See e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1kxct8h0.aspx.